# Delete all files in a directory w/o subdirectories with Apache Ant

Tags: ant, delete-file

I need an Apache Ant target that deletes all files in a directory but does not touch subdirectories.

In my current approach I have to explicitly name the subdirectories I want to skip (atm just "src/").

```
<delete>
   <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" excludes="src/" />
</delete>
```

But I don't like it. That way I would have to modify the target everytime something changes in the subdirectory structure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should work:

```
<delete>
   <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
      <include name="*"/>
   </fileset>
</delete>
```

The `*` wildcard should only delete the files at the top level, not directories or subdirectories. If you wanted it to be recursive, you'd need to use `**/*` instead.

Comment: `<fileset dir="${dist.dir}" defaultexcludes="false">` would remove everything, like hidden directories etc.